# Does the Japanese version of Disgaea 5 have the DLC bonuses?

Tags: nintendo-switch, disgaea-5

[Quoted from Siliconera:](http://www.siliconera.com/2017/01/13/disgaea-5-complete-new-version-dlc-content-announced-nintendo-switch/)

> The Complete Disgaea®5 Experience – Enjoy the full Disgaea®5 story along with 8 bonus scenarios, 4 fan-favorite characters and 3 character classes from the Disgaea series!

This talks about the Disgaea 5: Complete for Nintendo Switch. However, I have the Makai Senki Disgaea 5 version of the game (Japanese Version).

So, does the JP version also has the DLC content found in Complete? Or do I have to download it from the store?

Comment: Everything I can find on the subject in English (just because I am Japanese doesn't mean I can read/speak it, unfortunately) says that the makaisenki version is just the JP release of the Disgaea 5 Complete edition. In fact, since the game isn't region-locked, some people were buying JP-imports, as the English subtitles (and possibly audio?) was on the JP disc. If that's truly the case, it appears there are no differences, functionality-wise, between the NA and JP releases.

Comment: Alright then. Thank you for your answer. This question was boggling me all evening...

Comment: Do you want me to post it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything I can find on the subject (in English) says that the makaisenki version is just the JP release of the NA Disgaea 5 Complete edition.

In fact, since the game isn't region-locked, some people were buying JP-imports, as the English subtitles (and possibly audio?) was also on the JP disc. If that's truly the case, it appears there are no differences, functionality-wise, between the NA and JP releases, at all.